# Mixed Content. was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-ec2, netlify

I am facing an issue that I can't resolve. I built an application with a React front end and a Node.js API. I deployed the API on an EC2 instance and connected everything. However, it only works when I use the front end on localhost. When I use Netlify with React, the following error appears:

> index-3ecf22b0.js:121 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fanciful-khapse-1438af.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://15.229.71.122:7070/sessions'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I tried some solutions found on the internet, such as adding the following to my index.html:

```html
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="upgrade-insecure-requests"
/>
```

However, it didn't solve the issue. I believe the problem, as indicated by the error, is that the API is in HTTP while the site is in HTTPS. One of the things I attempted was changing the baseURL to HTTPS in the services/api.js folder, but it didn't work and resulted in the error GET https://main--fanciful-khapse-1438af.netlify.app/vite.svg 404 (Not Found). Therefore, I think it should work with the API using HTTP.

### Run

To run the code, clone it from GitHub and run `npm install` in the terminal opened in the front-end folder. Now, simply execute `npm run dev` to start the application. It should work normally; however, upon opening the Netlify link, an error occurs.

GitHub: https://github.com/nesdark/products-inventory-front/blob/main/src/services/api.js

Netlify: https://main--fanciful-khapse-1438af.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Resources requested by a browser must be hosted on the same domain and using the same protocol. These are two security measures of browsers. The same domain you can disable by setting up CORS in the server of your requested resource. The other can not be fixed using this.

Resources that are loaded over http while your website is https is always going to be blocked. You are letting your users know that your website uses encryption while you might be handling the person's data unencrypted.

Your fix is to setup your resources using https. Sometimes you can define your resources as `//example.com` instead. Just remove the `http:` or `https:`. That way it will always use the same protocol as your website is running at the moment. However browsers are moving towards enforced https

Comment: It returned `index-de4c6f92.js:121 POST https://15.229.71.122:7070/sessions net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Comment: Correct.  I've visited your website and it stated `blocked`.  That's a security measure by browsers.